# Every command i'm entering is returning "Abort"

Tags: php, freebsd, memory-leak, php-fpm

I'm running FreeBSD and I started an instance of php-fpm. After that, every command I type (except kill and cd) just return "Abort".
Last time this happened host said I had a memory leak, probably caused by php-fpm, I'm assuming.
Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the first part is to reboot.  Secondly, find your memory leak OR, when the server comes back up, try the previous steps while having some sort of top session going to see if after starting the php-fpm module things go awry.

Memory leaks suck :(

Comment: +1, "Memory leaks suck" @blockhead, Looks like it actively developed. If it's version matched for your php install you might want to contact the php-fpm team to see if they're aware of any problems.

Answer (score 2):

`PHP-FPM` has special option to avoid memory leaks

```
max_requests - How much requests each process should execute before respawn. 
               Useful to work around memory leaks in 3rd party libraries.
               For endless request processing please specify 0.
```